# Printing on the same line using printf in nasm

Tags: printf, nasm

I'd like to be able to print to the same line, while using multiple calls to printf in nasm assembly.

eg:

```
SEGMENT .text
mov eax,5
push eax
push format_num
call printf
add esp,8

...other code

mov eax,6
push eax
push format_num
call printf
add esp,8

SEGMENT .data
format_num db "%d",10,0
```

results in

```
5
6
```

whereas I would like

```
56
```

Since 10 represents the Line Feed character, I would have thought that using

```
format_num db "%d",0
```

would work, but that results in nothing being printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush stdout after printing.